# Python sockets: How to optimize recv() parameter for better performance?

Tags: python, sockets

I've learned that for performance reasons data should ideally be transmitted in larger batches, in order to reduce overhead.

I'm sending sequences of numbers (0,1,2,3,4,....,**N**) via a socket from server to client.
Is there a formula I might apply to define the parameter of recv(formula), depending on how high **N** (128, 256, 512,.... ) is?

I already tried changing the parameter of recv(), for instance recv(1024) and recv(2048), but I have difficulty figuring out if it actually improves performance.

Thank you

Comment: `recv(N)` does not always return N bytes, it returns what is currently available *up to N* bytes. Thus enlarging N may make no difference at all. Real details about your protocol and your code are needed to enable optimization suggestions. Sockets don't transmit numbers, they transmit bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Recall Knuth's [rule](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/356635.356640)
about premature optimization.

Given that your benchmarking activities have not shown
any measured improvement in elapsed time,
you should follow the documentation's
[advice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)
and supply a buffersize of 4096.

---

For specific cases of app-level protocol,
host hardware, usage pattern, bandwidth, and WAN delay,
tuning that parameter can measurably affect performance.
You have demonstrated that in your use case
it has negligible effect.
Worry about improving other aspects of the code.